# How to persist client side object state between route navigations in Angular 5+

Tags: angular

I am new to this and was thinking of passing an object collection that I planned to persist on client side, and share between routes, post navigation. Would love some help in understanding what is it that I am missing when I expect a "Service" state to persist across route navigations.

I have seen the constructors of even AppModule get triggered after every route navigation, so was wondering, if Local Storage or persisting data to server the only answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LocalStorage and persisting to server are options; the common pattern that many applications (particularly larger ones) will use is a flux- or redux-like implementation.

In a nutshell, flux/redux-type implementations provide a single data store that any of your components can use, without reloading your single-page application (Angular, React, etc.) or passing a ton of data between components.

To use your example, this would be the process for your example of an object collection.

1. Application bootstraps
2. Application retrieves initial data (state) from your server
3. Application stores the state in a global object
4. When a component is instantiated, it retrieves the state from the global object

Because the state is all in one place (on the global object), any action that affects that global object will be reflected in any components that are using that piece of state.

That is a very incomplete picture of everything that redux/flux entails, but if you wanted to hand-roll just the persistence part of that, you could add your collection of objects to the DOM window, like this:

```
window.state = {};
window.state.collection = [{obj1}, {obj2}, {obj3}]


component.state.collection = window.state.collection;
component.state.collection.push({obj4});
```

For more information about flux, there's a ton of very details resources about it on the internet.  A specific implementation ("redux") can be found here https://redux.js.org/. An angular-specific implementation of redux is here: https://github.com/angular-redux/store .